# C++ - How to use PCRE with DevC++

Tags: c++, pcre, dev-c++

i don't know anymore about PCRE to get work in my project at DevC++. it always produce error code when i do some function like this :

```
#include <pcre.h>
```

and did you know, its not about `no such file or directory bla... bla...` but it say `Linker error`, i searching, googling and try some tutorials, and read documentation too. The result is 0. i wonder why people so easy to fix this problem. The stupid me. Maybe you smarter than me.

#### So please help me now ?

and the point

### Question: How to fix this problem, I use De

Comment: You need to download the library

Comment: Yes, i have done with that and i have place it in devc++ include directory too, all library work properly, but why pcre always make console print error code. Please, almost 3 days i spent times for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linker errors usually mean you have the definition of a function, but not it's implementation. In this case, as in most, you included the header file containing the function definitions of pcre but you did not link the library. You should link the library (project options) and recompile.

Comment: Oww i think so, but how to include it in devc++ sir, all google results relative to VisualC++

Comment: @MichaelAntonio I don't have devc++ here, but off the top of my head: 1) click on the Projects ->"Project Options"->"Parameters"
2) under "Linker", where it says: "Add Library or Object",
click that button,
3) scan across the list until you find the library you want to link and add it to the list.

Comment: wait i will try it out

Comment: Thanks Kevin, you don't lazy, you direct DevC== user without download it, amazing ... Thanks again